# Resolving conflicts found during Android Studio update

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm getting the following error during the update of Android studio. Anyone know how to resolve it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The patch can't update files because they are either missing or different.

Reinstall Android Studio.

Answer (score -1):

I run into a similar situation, conflicts while updating Android TV! Never used that package and my intention was to remove it and update everything else if possible. After some fiddling I run the command:

```
[path-to-android-sdk]/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update
```

and after 30 minutes it or so it said Done.
Opened up Android Studio and everything appears to be updated and working!